# Escaping a dot in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, escaping

I am trying to define an `enumerator` for `UserAgents`.

Something like,

```
private enum UserAgents
    {
        "MSIE 7.0",
        "MSIE 6.0",
        "MSIE 5.0",
    }
```

But the `compiler is not happy with this`.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: I also tried like escaping using a verbatim literal `@` and a '\' but that does not do the job.

Comment: Since when one can use strings as enumeration elements?

Comment: @All: Oops. My bad. Wrong usage of Enums. But, how to delete the question ?

Comment: this is also might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how enums work.

You need something like this:

```
private enum UserAgents
{
    MSIE70,
    MSIE60,
    MSIE50
}
```

But then you have to worry about getting the string value out of it, the flags don't match the string representation either. You could decorate them with [DescriptionAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) but then you still have to do all the work to pull the string out.

Best thing to do would be to define a static class `UserAgents` with public static readonly fields for each user agent type:

```
public static UserAgents
{
   public static readonly MSIE70 = "MSIE 7.0"; 
   //etc...
}
```

Then you can do `UserAgents.MSIE70` to access the field.

Answer (score 2):

```
private enum UserAgents
{
    MSIE70,
    MSIE60,
    MSIE50,
}
```

Try this!