# Iterate through properties of a custom enum

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Is it possible to iterate through properties of a custom enum?

My custom enum looks like this:

```
public class Sex
{
    public static readonly Sex Female = new Sex("xx", "Female");

    public static readonly Sex Male = new Sex("xy", "Male");

    internal string Value { get; private set; }

    internal string Description { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }

    protected Sex(string value, string description)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Description = description;
    }
```

I use it to enable an enum to "enumerate" with strings i.e. "xx", "xy"...

My question is if it is possible to iterate though all sexes with the goal to fill a DropDownList ListItems with value and description.

```
var ddlSex = new DropDownList()

foreach(var sex in typeof(Sex).<some_magic>)
{
    ddlSex.Items.Add(new ListItem(sex.ToString(), sex.GetDescription()));
}
```

My idea is to solve the problem with the System.Reflection library but I'm sure how.

Comment: Reflection is indeed a magical thing, but it's often a major overkill for things like this. Usually, unless a problem explicitly requires reflection - save it as a last resort.

Comment: Maybe you're right have you any other ideas how I can solve my problem?

Comment: What's a "custom enum"? That doesn't look like any kind of enum.

Comment: It's not a real enum. Here it is called a type-safe-enum pattern:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/424414/909980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = typeof(Sex).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select(f => (Sex)f.GetValue(null))
            .ToList();

foreach(var sex in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sex.ToString() + ":" + sex.GetDescription());
}
```

Comment: Definitely the right solution, but as I mentioned in my answer, it's worth organising your code so that the evaluation of list only happens once in your application runtime.

Comment: @RobLyndon I'll leave that part to the OP since it is not the point of the question.

Comment: @RobLyndon It would be nice to use it the way you described but "var sex" contains two elements which are "null" each containing the static members "Female" and "Male".

Comment: @RobLyndon + Christoph Brückmann, because it depends on the **order** of the fields' initialization. It should be done in a *static* constructor of the class, like `static Sex()  {   All = ...  }`

Comment: @L.B You're absolutely right. Thanks a lot (to both of you)! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use reflection, you should try to do it in one hit: usually in a static constructor.

Here, you could do this:

```
public class Sex
{
    public static readonly List<Sex> All = typeof(Sex).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Sex))
        .Select(f => (Sex)f.GetValue(null))
        .ToList();

    public static readonly Sex Female = new Sex("xx", "Female");

    public static readonly Sex Male = new Sex("xy", "Male");

    ...
}
```

Then you can just use `Sex.All`, and the reflection will only happen once in your runtime.  Your invocation will look like this:

```
foreach(var sex in Sex.All)
{
    this.ddlSex.Items.Add(new ListItem(sex.ToString(), sex.GetDescription()));
}
```