# Check if string list contains any enum string value

Tags: c#, linq, enums, .net-3.5

```
enum KnownError
{
    [StringValue("CODE-001")]
    CODE001,
    [StringValue("CODE-002")]
    CODE002,
    [StringValue("CODE-003")]
    CODE003,
    [StringValue("CODE-004")]
    CODE004,
    [StringValue("CODE-005")]
    CODE005
}

List<string> errors = {"ahah", "eheh", "CODE-005", "uhuh"};
```

Let's say i have a list of string errors.
How can I check if any error is "known"?

```
bool ContainsKnownError(List<string> error)
{
    return errors.Where(error => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KnownError), error) == true).Count() > 0;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.
How can I access StringValue inside the linq query without having to compare each string?

**EDIT**

I tried @AK_ solution, using Intersect, but I'm getting this compilation error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

The real scenario is an Error object with a string field with the code like this

```
class Error { string code; }

List<Error> errors = GetErrors();
var knownErrors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownError));
bool exists = errors.Select(error => error.code).Intersect(knownErrors).Any();
```

Comment: So your issue is that the error code is not exactly same as `enum`, but instead its string value, right ?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer either at http://stackoverflow.com/q/424366/56778, or possibly http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C. You should mention in your question that `StringValue` is a custom attribute, *not* something that's supplied by .NET.

Comment: @Habib Yes, I just created an enum to make it easier to handle the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var knownErrors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownError));

return errors.Contains(error => knownErrors.Contains(error));
//or cooler:
return errors.Intersect(knownErrors).Count() > 0;
```

---

Zack's comment is correct:`return errors.Intersect(knownErrors).Any` is better...
+1 him :-)

Comment: I'd change `return errors.Intersect(knownErrors).Count() > 0;` to `return errors.Intersect(knownErrors).Any();` because `Any()` will terminate at the first match, rather than after processing every element of both sets (which `Count()` will do).

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.IsDefined` expects an object-wrapped instance of the `enum`. Passing a string name does not produce the desired result.

This should work:

```
KnownError ignore;
var res = errors.Any(errorCode => Enum.TryParse<KnownError>(errorCode, out ignore));
```

Note the use of LINQ's `Any` in place of comparing `Count()` to zero: this approach is more efficient, because it stops as soon as it finds the first match.