# Switch Case Returns "A Constant Value is expected"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, enums

I searched around, everyone else who had this problem was using the .ToString method and I am not so I am at a loss.

On the last line I get a return of "A Constant Value is expected"

I know if I remove the part where I give the enum's values it works, but that kinda defeats the purpose of me using an Enum.  Any suggestions about the best way to accomplish this?

```
        public enum Colors
    {
        Blue = "0000FF",
        Red = "FF0000",
        Green= "00FF00"
    }
        private void colorstuff(Colors Color){
            switch (Color ){
                case Colors.Blue:

            }
        }
```

**EDIT So I have been made aware that ENUM's cannot have a STRING type.  Can anyone suggest a method for making a SET of String Types?  If I just declare

```
        const Blue = "0000FF",
        const Red = "FF0000",
        const Green= "00FF00"
```

They are not attached to one another.

Comment: Why not add the color value as an attribute on your enum and use an extension method when you need to use the string value?

Comment: I am very new to c#.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @ cade http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums

Comment: Enums can't have string types...

Answer (score 2):

Enums are based on int data type, so you need to declare them like this:

```
Blue = 0x0000FF
```

Alternatively declare a class:

```
    public static class MyColours
    {
        public  const string Blue = "0000FF";
    }
```

Comment: So my Enum section won't even compile?  Good deal.

Comment: Well, `int` by default - but you can specify other integer-based types as the underlying type too.

Comment: The above example is just fake code to make my example.  I actually need something with a string value.  I need an underlying value to be a string and I would like it to work exactly like an ENUM does instead of having detached constants by just declaring 

const String Blue="0000FF";

How would I create a "SET" of constants that all have string values?

Comment: What if I create a new public class and made the sub constants public also.

Does this look like a good alternative? Does anyone see any potential issues using this method?  This just seems like an odd way to accomplish this.'
`code
    public static class Colors
    {
        public String Value="";
        public const String Blue = "0000FF";
        public const String Red = "FF0000";
        public const String Green= "00FF00";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

dear you can't define enum like this , because it's int type.

```
 public enum Colors
    {
        Blue = 0000FF,
        Red = FF0000,
        Green= 00FF00
    }
```

Comment: Your piece of code would not "compile". How is it supposed to answer OP's question?