# Getting attributes of Enum's value

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, .net-attributes

I would like to know if it is possible to get attributes of the `enum` values and not of the `enum` itself? For example, suppose I have the following `enum`:

```
using System.ComponentModel; // for DescriptionAttribute

enum FunkyAttributesEnum
{
    [Description("Name With Spaces1")]
    NameWithoutSpaces1,    
    [Description("Name With Spaces2")]
    NameWithoutSpaces2
}
```

What I want is given the enum type, produce 2-tuples of enum string value and its description.

Value was easy:

```
Array values = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(FunkyAttributesEnum));
foreach (int value in values)
    Tuple.Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(FunkyAttributesEnum), value);
```

But how do I get description attribute's value, to populate `Tuple.Desc`? I can think of how to do it if the Attribute belongs to the `enum` itself, but I am at a loss as to how to get it from the value of the `enum`.

Comment: From another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-sharp-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c/4778347#4778347

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know a quick way to get to custom attributes on an enum value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772/anyone-know-a-quick-way-to-get-to-custom-attributes-on-an-enum-value)

Comment: namespace required for Description is System.ComponentModel

Comment: You can also just not use System.ComponentModel and just use your own attribute type; there's really nothing all that special about `DescriptionAttribute`.

Comment: plesae see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58954215/5576498

Answer (score 544, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```cs
try
{
  var enumType = typeof(FunkyAttributesEnum);
  var memberInfos = 
  enumType.GetMember(FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1.ToString());
  var enumValueMemberInfo = memberInfos.FirstOrDefault(m => 
  m.DeclaringType == enumType);
  var valueAttributes = 
  enumValueMemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
  var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)valueAttributes[0]).Description;
}
catch
{
    return FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1.ToString()
}
```

Comment: Optionally use type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) to get all the memInfos at once.

Comment: I had to go typeof(FunkyAttributesEnum), but other than that it worked well. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexK I don't see Enum class has a NameWithoutSpaces1 property.  Where does the FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1 come from?

Comment: @Don, it's the enum member name from the OP's question.

Answer (score 379):

This piece of code should give you a nice little extension method on any enum that lets you retrieve a generic attribute.  I believe it's different to the lambda function above because it's simpler to use and slightly - you only need to pass in the generic type.

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an attribute on an enum field value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the attribute you want to retrieve</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumVal">The enum value</param>
    /// <returns>The attribute of type T that exists on the enum value</returns>
    /// <example><![CDATA[string desc = myEnumVariable.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;]]></example>
    public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T:System.Attribute
    {
        var type = enumVal.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? (T)attributes[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
string desc = myEnumVariable.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;
```

Comment: I like this one more than Scott's, because the usage is cleaner here (less typing), so +1 :)

Comment: If no attribute exists, wouldn't this throw a `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - It returns an empty string if no attribute exists.

Comment: better use type.GetMember(Enum.GetName(type, enumVal)) for the memInfo as enumVal.ToString() may not be reliable for different locales.

Comment: What is the point of calling `GetCustomAttributes()` then get first element instead of calling `GetCustomAttribute()` ?

Comment: @tigrou this extension was added quite recently to the .NET framework; the solution (which is from 2009) might need an update.

Comment: @ManuelFaux which version of the framework?

Answer (score 94):

This is a generic implementation using a lambda for the selection

```
public static Expected GetAttributeValue<T, Expected>(this Enum enumeration, Func<T, Expected> expression)
    where T : Attribute
{
    T attribute =
      enumeration
        .GetType()
        .GetMember(enumeration.ToString())
        .Where(member => member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
        .Cast<T>()
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (attribute == null)
        return default(Expected);

    return expression(attribute);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
string description = targetLevel.GetAttributeValue<DescriptionAttribute, string>(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: This is great. We just have to be carefull if the given enumeration value is a combination (allowed by `FlagsAttribute`). In this case, `enumeration.GetType().GetMember(enumeration.ToString())[0]` will fail.

Comment: The shortest you could write: `value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<T>‌​().SingleOrDefault()`, but have to admit your explicit way is better.

Comment: I also add      public static String GetDescription(this Enum enumeration)
        {
            return enumeration.GetAttributeValue<DescriptionAttribute, String>(x => x.Description);
        }     that way its just targetLevel.GetDescription();

Answer (score 85):

I've merged a couple of the answers here to create a little more extensible solution. I'm providing it just in case it's helpful to anyone else in the future. Original posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621436/1454806).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static class EnumExtensions {

    // This extension method is broken out so you can use a similar pattern with 
    // other MetaData elements in the future. This is your base method for each.
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 
          ? (T)attributes[0]
          : null;
    }

    // This method creates a specific call to the above method, requesting the
    // Description MetaData attribute.
    public static string ToName(this Enum value) {
        var attribute = value.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }

}
```

This solution creates a pair of extension methods on Enum. The first allows you to use reflection to retrieve any attribute associated with your value. The second specifically calls retrieves the `DescriptionAttribute` and returns it's `Description` value.

As an example, consider using the `DescriptionAttribute` attribute from `System.ComponentModel`

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum Days {
    [Description("Sunday")]
    Sun,
    [Description("Monday")]
    Mon,
    [Description("Tuesday")]
    Tue,
    [Description("Wednesday")]
    Wed,
    [Description("Thursday")]
    Thu,
    [Description("Friday")]
    Fri,
    [Description("Saturday")]
    Sat
}
```

To use the above extension method, you would now simply call the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(Days.Mon.ToName());
```

or

```
var day = Days.Mon;
Console.WriteLine(day.ToName());
```

Comment: On the last line, you mean "attribute.Description" ?
return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;

Comment: Best and simplest answer.

Answer (score 38):

In addition to [AdamCrawford response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276348/209259), I've further created a more specialized extension methods that feed of it to get the description.

```
public static string GetAttributeDescription(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var attribute = enumValue.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>();
    return attribute == null ? String.Empty : attribute.Description;
}
```

hence, to get the description, you could either use the original extension method as

```
string desc = myEnumVariable.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description
```

or you could simply call the the extension method here as:

```
string desc = myEnumVariable.GetAttributeDescription();
```

Which should hopefully make your code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 24):

**Fluent one liner...**

Here I'm using the `DisplayAttribute` which contains both the `Name` and `Description` properties.

```
public static DisplayAttribute GetDisplayAttributesFrom(this Enum enumValue, Type enumType)
{
    return enumType.GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                   .First()
                   .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
}
```

---

**Example**

```
public enum ModesOfTransport
{
    [Display(Name = "Driving",    Description = "Driving a car")]        Land,
    [Display(Name = "Flying",     Description = "Flying on a plane")]    Air,
    [Display(Name = "Sea cruise", Description = "Cruising on a dinghy")] Sea
}

void Main()
{
    ModesOfTransport TransportMode = ModesOfTransport.Sea;
    DisplayAttribute metadata = TransportMode.GetDisplayAttributesFrom(typeof(ModesOfTransport));
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} \nDescription: {1}", metadata.Name, metadata.Description);
}
```

---

#### Output

```
Name: Sea cruise 
Description: Cruising on a dinghy
```

Comment: I use this too, it's the most clean of all the answers! +1

Comment: This seems to be quite useful! Thnx

Comment: You can use enumValue.GetType() to eliminate the enumType argument.

Answer (score 7):

Here is code to get information from a Display attribute. It uses a generic method to retrieve the attribute. If the attribute is not found it converts the enum value to a string with pascal/camel case converted to title case (code obtained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155486/150342))

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    // Get the Name value of the Display attribute if the   
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value converted to title case.  
    public static string GetDisplayName<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var attr = value.GetAttributeOfType<TEnum, DisplayAttribute>();
        return attr == null ? value.ToString().ToSpacedTitleCase() : attr.Name;
    }

    // Get the ShortName value of the Display attribute if the   
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value converted to title case.  
    public static string GetDisplayShortName<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var attr = value.GetAttributeOfType<TEnum, DisplayAttribute>();
        return attr == null ? value.ToString().ToSpacedTitleCase() : attr.ShortName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an attribute on an enum field value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEnum">The enum type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the attribute you want to retrieve</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">The enum value</param>
    /// <returns>The attribute of type T that exists on the enum value</returns>
    private static T GetAttributeOfType<TEnum, T>(this TEnum value)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
        where T : Attribute
    {

        return value.GetType()
                    .GetMember(value.ToString())
                    .First()
                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<T>()
                    .LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And this is the extension method for strings for converting to title case:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts camel case or pascal case to separate words with title case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToSpacedTitleCase(this string s)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/155486/150342
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
        return textInfo
           .ToTitleCase(Regex.Replace(s, 
                        "([a-z](?=[A-Z0-9])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "$1 "));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If your `enum` contains a value like `Equals` you might bump into a few bugs using some extensions in a lot of answers here. This is because it is normally assumed that `typeof(YourEnum).GetMember(YourEnum.Value)` would return only one value, which is the `MemberInfo` of your `enum`. Here's a slightly safer version [Adam Crawford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276348/209259).

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    #region Methods

    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum enumValue) where T : Attribute
    {
        var type = enumValue.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumValue.ToString());
        var member = memberInfo.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DeclaringType == type);
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(T), false);
        return attribute is T ? (T)attribute : null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### Edit (3rd May 2023)

`GetField` works well in this case. `typeof(YourEnum).GetField(YourEnum.Value)` should produce the desired result.

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    FieldInfo field = type.GetField(value.ToString());

    Attribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(T), false);
    return (T)attr;
}
```

Thanks to [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) for pointing this out.

Comment: Could `GetField` be used rather than `GetMember`?

Comment: Yes, it appears you can actually. I will update the answer accordingly, good catch!

Answer (score 5):

For some programmer humor, a one liner as a joke:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value) => value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString()).First().GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>() is DescriptionAttribute attribute ? attribute.Description : string.Empty;
```

In a more readable form:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    // get description from enum:

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        return value.GetType().
            GetMember(value.ToString()).
            First().
            GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>() is DescriptionAttribute attribute
            ? attribute.Description
            : throw new Exception($"Enum member '{value.GetType()}.{value}' doesn't have a [DescriptionAttribute]!");
    }

    // get enum from description:

    public static T GetEnum<T>(this string description) where T : Enum
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            if (fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>() is DescriptionAttribute attribute && attribute.Description == description)
                return (T)fieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue();
        }

        throw new Exception($"Enum '{typeof(T)}' doesn't have a member with a [DescriptionAttribute('{description}')]!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer the first implementation ironically enough. I'm more accustomed to functional style programming in C# and found it to be more readable. :)

Answer (score 4):

Get the dictionary from enum.

```
public static IDictionary<string, int> ToDictionary(this Type enumType)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(enumType)
    .Cast<object>()
    .ToDictionary(v => ((Enum)v).ToEnumDescription(), k => (int)k); 
}
```

Now call this like...

```
var dic = typeof(ActivityType).ToDictionary();
```

EnumDecription Ext Method

```
public static string ToEnumDescription(this Enum en) //ext method
{
    Type type = en.GetType();
    MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
    }
    return en.ToString();
}

public enum ActivityType
{
    [Description("Drip Plan Email")]
    DripPlanEmail = 1,
    [Description("Modification")]
    Modification = 2,
    [Description("View")]
    View = 3,
    [Description("E-Alert Sent")]
    EAlertSent = 4,
    [Description("E-Alert View")]
    EAlertView = 5
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I this answer to setup a combo box from an enum attributes which was great.

I then needed to code the reverse so that I can get the selection from the box and return the enum in the correct type.

I also modified the code to handle the case where an attribute was missing

For the benefits of the next person, here is my final solution

```
public static class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // display the description attribute from the enum
       foreach (Colour type in (Colour[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colour)))
       {
            Console.WriteLine(EnumExtensions.ToName(type));
       }

       // Get the array from the description
       string xStr = "Yellow";
       Colour thisColour = EnumExtensions.FromName<Colour>(xStr);

       Console.ReadLine();
    }

   public enum Colour
   {
       [Description("Colour Red")]
       Red = 0,

       [Description("Colour Green")]
       Green = 1,

       [Description("Colour Blue")]
       Blue = 2,

       Yellow = 3
   }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{

    // This extension method is broken out so you can use a similar pattern with 
    // other MetaData elements in the future. This is your base method for each.
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);

        // check if no attributes have been specified.
        if (((Array)attributes).Length > 0)
        {
            return (T)attributes[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // This method creates a specific call to the above method, requesting the
    // Description MetaData attribute.
    public static string ToName(this Enum value)
    {
        var attribute = value.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the enum from the description attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="desc"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T FromName<T>(this string desc) where T : struct
    {
        string attr;
        Boolean found = false;
        T result = (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).GetValue(0);

        foreach (object enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            attr = ((Enum)enumVal).ToName();

            if (attr == desc)
            {
                result = (T)enumVal;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Man I have seen so many stupid and unexplained solutions, and yours killed it. Thank you a lot <3

Answer (score 4):

### Performance matters

If you want better performance this is the way to go:

```
public static class AdvancedEnumExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the custom attribute <typeparamref name="T"/> for the enum constant, if such a constant is defined and has such an attribute; otherwise null.
    /// </summary>
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute
    {
        return GetField(value)?.GetCustomAttribute<T>(inherit: false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the FieldInfo for the enum constant, if such a constant is defined; otherwise null.
    /// </summary>
    public static FieldInfo GetField(this Enum value)
    {
        ulong u64 = ToUInt64(value);
        return value
            .GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(f => ToUInt64(f.GetRawConstantValue()) == u64)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if an enum constant is defined for this enum value
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsDefined(this Enum value)
    {
        return GetField(value) != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the enum value to UInt64
    /// </summary>
    public static ulong ToUInt64(this Enum value) => ToUInt64((object)value);

    private static ulong ToUInt64(object value)
    {
        switch (Convert.GetTypeCode(value))
        {
            case TypeCode.SByte:
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                return unchecked((ulong)Convert.ToInt64(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            case TypeCode.Byte:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
            case TypeCode.Char:
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return Convert.ToUInt64(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            default: throw new InvalidOperationException("UnknownEnumType");
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this have better performance?

Because the built-in methods all use code very similar to this except *they also run a bunch of other code we don't care about*. C#'s Enum code is quite horrible in general.

The above code has been Linq-ified and streamlined so it only contains the bits we care about.

### Why is the built-in code slow?

First regarding Enum.ToString() -vs- Enum.GetName(..)

Always use the latter. (Or better yet neither, as will become clear below.)

ToString() uses the latter internally, but again, also does a bunch of other stuff we don't want, e.g. tries to combine flags, print out numbers etc. We are only interested in constants defined inside the enum.

Enum.GetName in turn gets all fields, creates a string array for all names, uses the above ToUInt64 on all of their RawConstantValues to create an UInt64 array of all values, sorts both arrays according to the UInt64 value, and finally gets the name from the name-array by doing a BinarySearch in the UInt64-array to find the index of the value we wanted.

...and then we throw the fields and the sorted arrays away use that name to find the field again.

One word: "Ugh!"

Comment: This could be further improved for performance with some caching, but then it goes into "over-engineering" land. That's where I decided that using an external library would be the best approach.

Comment: You can abuse the type-system by making the extensions generic and then cache in static fields. You basically shove the performance responsibility onto the type system, but it's very easy to implement and thread-safety is trivial to uphold since you don't have to deal with mutability. The above would still be the component that does the actual "work" - caching should be implemented as a layer above that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the .NET Core version of AdamCrawford's answer, using [System.Reflection.TypeExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/);

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an attribute on an enum field value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the attribute you want to retrieve</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumVal">The enum value</param>
    /// <returns>The attribute of type T that exists on the enum value</returns>
    /// <example>string desc = myEnumVariable.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;</example>
    public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T : System.Attribute
    {
        var type = enumVal.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return (T)attributes?.ToArray()[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding my solution for Net Framework and NetCore.

I used this for my Net Framework implementation:

```
public static class EnumerationExtension
{
    public static string Description( this Enum value )
    {
        // get attributes  
        var field = value.GetType().GetField( value.ToString() );
        var attributes = field.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( DescriptionAttribute ), false );

        // return description
        return attributes.Any() ? ( (DescriptionAttribute)attributes.ElementAt( 0 ) ).Description : "Description Not Found";
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for NetCore so I modified it to do this:

```
public static class EnumerationExtension
{
    public static string Description( this Enum value )
    {
        // get attributes  
        var field = value.GetType().GetField( value.ToString() );
        var attributes = field.GetCustomAttributes( false );

        // Description is in a hidden Attribute class called DisplayAttribute
        // Not to be confused with DisplayNameAttribute
        dynamic displayAttribute = null;

        if (attributes.Any())
        {
            displayAttribute = attributes.ElementAt( 0 );
        }

        // return description
        return displayAttribute?.Description ?? "Description Not Found";
    }
}
```

Enumeration Example:

```
public enum ExportTypes
{
    [Display( Name = "csv", Description = "text/csv" )]
    CSV = 0
}
```

Sample Usage for either static added:

```
var myDescription = myEnum.Description();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Bryan Rowe** and **AdamCrawford** thanks for your answers!

But if somebody need method for get Discription (not extension) you can use it:

```
string GetEnumDiscription(Enum EnumValue)
        {
            var type = EnumValue.GetType();
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(EnumValue.ToString());
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return (attributes.Length > 0) ? ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description : null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this extension method to get the description from enum values. It works for all kind of enums.

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string ToDescription(this System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: generic version of the same solution is already posted. imo, better.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of some of the newer C# language features, you can reduce the line count:

```
public static TAttribute GetEnumAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumVal) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var memberInfo = enumVal.GetType().GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
    return memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).OfType<TAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
}

public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum enumValue) => enumValue.GetEnumAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? enumValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

## Model

The model in which we fill our values

```
public class MemberTypeModel : IDto
{
    public string MemberAttributeName { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public int MemberValue { get; set; }
}
```

## Enum

Our target is the enum

```
public enum MemberType
{
    [FieldText("Yönetim Kurul Üyesi")]
    BoardManager = 0,

    [FieldText("Temsilci")]
    Representative = 1,

    [FieldText("Üye")]
    Member = 2
}
```

## Helper Method

The helper method we will use to fetch the custom attribute object

```
public T GetMemberCustomText<T>(MemberType memberType) where T : Attribute
{
    var enumType = memberType.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, memberType);
    return enumType.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault();
}
```

## Get Method

First we pull enum values and cast them to enum type. Then, with the Linq selection query we know;

- MemberAttributeName field with helper method,
- MemberName field with Enum.GetName method,
- Casting the MemberValue field to an int type as well,
  We fill it out and turn it into a list.

---

```
public List<MemberTypeModel> GetMemberTypes()
{
    var memberTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MemberType))
        .Cast<MemberType>()
        .Select(et => new MemberTypeModel
        {
            MemberAttributeName = GetMemberCustomText<FieldText>(et).Text,
            MemberName = Enum.GetName(et.GetType(), et),
            MemberValue = (int)et
        }).ToList();
    return memberTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public enum DataFilters
    {
        [Display(Name= "Equals")]
        Equals = 1,// Display Name and Enum Name are same 
        [Display(Name= "Does Not Equal")]
        DoesNotEqual = 2, // Display Name and Enum Name are different             
    }
```

Now it will produce error in this case 1 "Equals"

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        var enumMember = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString()).First();
        return enumMember.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>() != null ? enumMember.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name : enumMember.Name;
    }
```

so if it is same return enum name rather than display name because 
    enumMember.GetCustomAttribute()
gets null if displayname and enum name are same.....

Comment: This solution fetches the attribute twice, which causes an unnecessary overhead. Consider fetching it once, and if it's not null, return it's `Name` property. For example `var attr = enumMember.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(); return attr != null ? attr.Name : enumMember.Name;`

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package [Enums.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Enums.NET) has good support for this:

```
var value = FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1;
string description = value.AsString(EnumFormat.Description); // => "Name With Spaces1"
```

The package is simple, intuitive, and complete.
It's type-safe and has cache to avoid recurring reflection.

The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET) has more information, including the limitations of the native Enum and a demo of functionality:

- Getting attributes;
- Flag operations;
- Enum formats (for ToString or to parse the enum from string);
- Rich iteration of all values with `Enums.GetMembers<MyEnum>()`;
- Etc.

Answer (score 0):

This extension method will obtain a string representation of an enum value using its XmlEnumAttribute. If no XmlEnumAttribute is present, it falls back to enum.ToString().

```
public static string ToStringUsingXmlEnumAttribute<T>(this T enumValue)
    where T: struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    }

    string name;

    var type = typeof(T);

    var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumValue.ToString());

    if (memInfo.Length == 1)
    {
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length == 1)
        {
            name = ((System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
        }
        else
        {
            name = enumValue.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        name = enumValue.ToString();
    }

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want the full list of names you can do something like

```
typeof (PharmacyConfigurationKeys).GetFields()
        .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(y => typeof(DescriptionAttribute) == y.GetType()))
        .Select(x => ((DescriptionAttribute)x.GetCustomAttributes(false)[0]).Description);
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
Dictionary<FunkyAttributesEnum, string> description = new Dictionary<FunkyAttributesEnum, string>()
    {
      { FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1, "Name With Spaces1" },
      { FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces2, "Name With Spaces2" },
    };
```

And get the description with the following:

```
string s = description[FunkyAttributesEnum.NameWithoutSpaces1];
```

In my opinion this is a more efficient way of doing what you want to accomplish, as no reflection is needed..

Comment: Sure, but reflection isn't nearly as bad as people make it out to be.

Comment: Not saying it's bad -- I use it all the time. It is often used needlessly, though. :)

Comment: This solution moves the description away from the enum itself, creating at least two big problems. First, if someone adds a new enum constant , they will need to know to go to this other place to add an entry there as well. Attributes are a clear sign to a maintainer of what they need to do. My second problem with it is that it's just a lot more code. Attributes are compact.

Comment: @scott but it does let you specify your own order, and exclude values you don't want to display which is *nearly* always what I actually want

Comment: @Simon_Weaver be careful, [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) that «**The order** in which the items are returned (from the dictionary) **is undefined**.».

Answer (score -1):

Guys if it helps I will share with you my solution: 
Definition of Custom attribute:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumDisplayName : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public EnumDisplayName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Now because I needed it inside of HtmlHelper definition of HtmlHelper Extension:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static string EnumDisplayName(this HtmlHelper helper,EPriceType priceType)
    {
        //Get every fields from enum
        var fields = priceType.GetType().GetFields();
        //Foreach field skipping 1`st fieldw which keeps currently sellected value
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length;i++ )
        {
            //find field with same int value
            if ((int)fields[i].GetValue(priceType) == (int)priceType)
            {
                //get attributes of found field
                var attributes = fields[i].GetCustomAttributes(false);
                if (attributes.Length > 0)
                {
                    //return name of found attribute
                    var retAttr = (EnumDisplayName)attributes[0];
                    return retAttr.Name;
                }
            }
        }
        //throw Error if not found
        throw new Exception("Błąd podczas ustalania atrybutów dla typu ceny allegro");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in typeof(PaymentTerm).GetEnumValues())
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var name = type.GetField(item.ToString()).GetCustomAttributesData().FirstOrDefault()?.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault().TypedValue.Value.ToString();
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem(name, type.Name));

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created an extension method that will return description of all the elements in an enum in C#.

```
public static List<string> GetAllEnumDescriptions(this Type enumType)
    {
        try
        {
            var enumList = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Enum>().ToList();
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            foreach (var enumItem in enumList)
            {
                result.Add(enumItem.EnumDescription());
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

This method will add the description of the elements in an enum using the inbuilt EnumDescription() extension method.

Comment: `using the inbuilt EnumDescription() extension method` there is no such built-in method.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I solved it without using custom helpers or extensions with .NET core 3.1.

### Class

```
public enum YourEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Suryoye means Arameans")]
    SURYOYE = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Oromoye means Syriacs")]
    OROMOYE = 1,
}
```

### Razor

```
@using Enumerations

foreach (var name in Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(YourEnum)))
{
    <h1>@name.Text</h1>
}
```

Comment: consider answering the question using more than how you solved 'it' - start by acknowledging the problem and explaining how you think this solves 'it'. Remember your answer could be taken out of context in some years from now and it would then be almost useless. Adding more to it, adding some context would level up your answer and its possible historical/archival relevance