# How to get attributes of bitwise enum

Tags: c#, enums, system.reflection

I've bitwise enum that has multiple values each with a description attribute.

```
    [Flags]
public enum ParkingAreaType
{
    [Description("Car Park")]
    CarPark = 1,

    [Description("Residential Permit")]
    ResidentialPermitZone = 2,

    [Description("Commercial Permit")]
    CommercialPermitZone = 4,

    [Description("On Street Parking")]
    OnStreetParking = 8,

    Any =
        CarPark | ResidentialPermitZone | CommercialPermitZone 
}
```

I've used and tried multiple extensions methods that i found on a few other questions quite similar to this

[Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

[How to get attributes of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308481/how-to-get-attributes-of-enum)

Im currently using a the snippit of code from John Skeets EnumInternals 
https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody/blob/master/UnconstrainedMelody/EnumInternals.cs

```
private static string GetDescription(T value)
    {
        FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField(value.ToString());
        return field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                    .Select(x => x.Description)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The above code will work if i just pass in a single enum, but if i pass in a bitwise enum it will throw an Object Reference. I've tried a few different variations of the above from different examples but all with the same result.

I just cant figure out how to get a list of the descriptions that are passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there no field called `CarPark | ResidentialPermitZone | CommercialPermitZone` for instance (or `CarPark | ResidentialPermitZone` etc.)

You'll have to retrieve each value of the bit combinaison, for instance:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var parkingAreaType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ParkingAreaType)))
{
    if (value.HasFlag(parkingAreaType))
    {
        result.Add(GetDescription(parkingAreaType));
    }
}
```