# Use Attribute for Enum description

Tags: c#

I have a Enum and want to add a description foreach value. I read something about attributes, which could solve my problem. I try to implement the solution from msdn but without succes. It works if iam using a class but not with enum values.

Is it possible that someone post how that works?

regards

Heres a link to the msdn solution. Thats what i try to do. Only difference is that i want to do with enum value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Example:

```
public enum Color
{
  [Description("This is red")]
  Red,
  [Description("This is blue")]
  Blue
}
```

how can i get acces to the description and how i have to implement the description class/method?

Comment: Show us what you've tried maybe?

Comment: Can you link to the MSDN solution?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: Guys, don't know who downvoted him, but why don't you simply just wait for his reactions and THEN downvote if he doesn't improve the question? It's easy to hit `-`, isn't it?

Comment: @Nathum Litvin thanks this post was really helpfull. I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for enum

```
public enum MyColors{
[Description("Editor Color")]
White,
[Description("Errors Color")]
Red,
[Description("Comments Color")]
Green
}


var type = typeof(MyColors);
var memInfo = type.GetMember(MyColors.White.ToString());
var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
false);
var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you just copied it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value

Comment: @NahumLitvin well Dear, I have already used this code once in my application using this post. So i just copy and paste it from my code where i hv used it..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum MyColors{
   [Description("Editor Color")]
   White,
   [Description("Errors Color")]
   Red,
   [Description("Comments Color")]
   Green
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do. But how can i get acces on description. Thats my problem.