# Testing for CLSCompliance (or testing for any attribute)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, attributes, custom-attributes

Here is a code snippet of an enum I defined:

```
public enum DataTypes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class.
    /// </summary>
    Object = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// True / false.
    /// </summary>
    Boolean = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Signed 8 bit integer.
    /// </summary>
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    Int8 = 2,
```

How do I test an item for CLSCompliant true / false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting attributes of Enum's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I test an item for CLSCompliant true / false?

You get the relevant `FieldInfo` using `Type.GetField`, and then use [`MemberInfo.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx).

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

public enum DemoEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar,
    [Description("This is a baz")]
    Baz
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(DemoEnum)))
        {
            var field = typeof(DemoEnum).GetField(name);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name,
                              field.IsDefined(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                                              false));
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the actual attribute value, you'd need to use [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks Jon :) I adapted this, used Enum.GetName() to directly get the one I want, and it works perfectly. It seems a bit heavy that one has to use the string name to get this, rather that passing the (int)enum type, but I guess that's because this operates on methods too.

Comment: @IanC: Well you're trying to get the *field* - and there could be multiple fields with the same value within an enum.