# get enum String Value

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have this Enum:

```
public enum SalaryAgreements
{
    [EnumStringValue("ללא")]
    Non,
    [EnumStringValue("הסכם 3")]
    Agree3,
    [EnumStringValue("הסכם 5")]
    Agree5,
}
```

And I need to get the "EnumStringValue". How can I do that?

I tried `toString()` and:

```
SalaryAgreements agreement;         
if ((guider.SalaryAgree != null) || (guider.SalaryAgree == 0))
{
    agreement = (guider.SalaryAgree == 1 ? SalaryAgreements.Agree3 : SalaryAgreements.Agree5);
}
else
{
    agreement = SalaryAgreements.Non;
}
this.salaryAgree = Enum.GetName(agreement.GetType(), agreement);
```

But i get only the `Non`, `Agree3`, `Agree5`. I need the values like `ללא` and `הסכם`.

This is similar to [Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value), but they are working with description and I need `EnumStringValue`. I wasn't able to make their examples to work.

Comment: public static EnumStringValueAttribute GetConcreteAttribute(Enum enumValue)
{
FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString());
if (fieldInfo != null)
{
   object[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumStringValueAttribute), false);
   if (attributes.Length > 0)
   {
       EnumStringValueAttribute attr = attributes[0] as EnumStringValueAttribute;
   if (attr != null)
   {
       return attr;
   }
}
}
            return null;
}

Comment: Vote to reopen the question, and then place the code in an Answer block. I think the question was closed due to a misunderstanding, and it was likely because English is not the primary language.