# Enum value not being recognised correctly

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

I have some enums which i have set up as follows:

```
public enum MyDefaultEnums
{
    [EnumMember(Value="My First Enum")]enum1,
    [EnumMember(Value="My Second Enum")]enum2,
}
```

Then I run a method which checks a given textbox (tb) to see what text is in it.  If the value is there in the enum list, it clears it, if it isn't, it leaves it alone:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyDefaultEnums), tb.Text) == true)
        {
            tb.Text = "";  
        }
```

However, its not working. Debugging at runtime shows me that MyDefaultEnums is picking the values up as enum1 and enum2, instead of the strings i put in there.  Can anyone point me to where im going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value) should show you how to do it.

Comment: Hmm - that post implies that it is assigning a var (meminfo) to each enum attribute individually (NameWithoutSpaces1) - or am i missing something?  As my enum grows, that's not something i want to do

Comment: and if you have to do it that way, whats the point in setting the enum value via EnumMember(Value= ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get all custom attribute values

```
var enumValues = typeof(MyDefaultEnums)
    .GetFields()
    .SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false))
    .Cast<EnumMemberAttribute>()
    .Select(a => a.Value);
```

Then just check if your value in that array

```
if (enumValues.Contains(tb.Text))
    tb.Text = "";
```

---

You can put this code into helper class

```
public class Enum<TEnum>
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetMemberValues()
    {
        return typeof(TEnum).GetFields()
            .SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false))
            .Cast<EnumMemberAttribute>()
            .Select(a => a.Value);
    }
}
```

Now check is simple as

```
if (Enum<MyDefaultEnums>.GetMemberValues().Contains(tb.Text))
    tb.Text = "";
```

And you can use it with any enum marked with `EnumMember` attributes

Comment: IDE isn't recognizing .GetFields().  MSDN implies its in the system namespace, which is obviously set, but its not having it

Comment: @Ricardinho make sure [GetFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is available in your framework. Is it Mono? Also make sure you didn't miss `typeof` part

Comment: I can see it in the references under system.type, which im using in the project,  but its not being recognised.  Not sure what you mean by mono though

Comment: The error im seeing is 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetFields' and no extension method 'GetFields' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yeah - i have used typeof

Comment: @Ricardinho maybe you haven't specified that you are developing Win Phone application?

Comment: @Ricardinho if my guess is correct, then according to [Evolving Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) you should use GetTypeInfo

Comment: yeah, your right, its a windows phone app (sorry for the confusion).  After adding system.reflection, i do get GetTypeInfo().  But then it doesnt recognise selectionmany ...

Comment: @Ricardinho its a `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: So should i still be able to run selectmany with GetTypeInfo()?  Ive added using system.Linq to my project, but its still telling my that system.reflection.typeinfo does not contain a definition for SelectMany

Comment: @Ricardinho `SelectMany` is an extension method. See `Linq`