# Enum Reflection with .NET Core

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get the `DisplayAttribute` properties working for an `enum`, so I can list out the values available (to expose to a RESTful API).

I have an enumeration as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Available Proposal Types
/// </summary>
public enum ProposalTypes
{
    Undefined = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Propose an administrative action.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Administrative", Description = "Propose an administrative action.")]
    Administrative,

    /// <summary>
    /// Propose some other action.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Miscellaneous", Description = "Propose some other action.")]
    Miscellaneous
}
```

I then made some helper methods like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     A generic extension method that aids in reflecting
    ///     and retrieving any attribute that is applied to an `Enum`.
    /// </summary>
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var type = enumValue.GetType();
        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        var attributes = typeInfo.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>();
        var attribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault();
        return attribute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of possible values and their associated descriptions for a type of enumeration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEnum"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IDictionary<string, string> GetEnumPossibilities<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
    {
        var type = typeof(TEnum);
        var info = type.GetTypeInfo();
        if (!info.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified type is not an enumeration.");


        var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var enumName in Enum.GetNames(type)
            .Where(x => !x.Equals("Undefined", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var value = (Enum)Enum.Parse(type, enumName);
            var displayAttribute = value.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            results[enumName] = $"{displayAttribute?.Name ?? enumName}: {displayAttribute?.Description ?? enumName}";
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The usage for this would be:

```
var types = Reflection.GetEnumPossibilities<ProposalTypes>();
```

What seems to be happening, though, is in the `GetAttribute<TAttribute>` method, when I attempt to get the attribute I'm looking for with:

```
var attributes = typeInfo.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>();
```

...the resultant value is an empty enumeration, thus returning back a null value.  From everything I've read, that should work just fine, and I should get back the associated `DisplayAttribute`... but I get back a null value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing with this Dictionary (return value of `GetEnumPossibilities`) at the end? If you are returning this somewhere as JSON you are going through a lot of trouble unnecessarily. JSON.NET will serialize your attributes properly.

Comment: @HristoYankov I am using this to create an endpoint that defines the possible types to inform an API consumer front end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking for attributes on the type ProposalTypes, not the values of the type. [See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/)  for info on getting the attributes of the enum values.

More precisely in `GetAttribute` you'll need to get the member that represents your specific value and call `GetCustomAttributes` on that. Your method will then look like this:

```
public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var type = enumValue.GetType();
    var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
    var memberInfo = typeInfo.GetMember(enumValue.ToString());
    var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>();
    var attribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault();
    return attribute;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I was looking at an enum value as its own type, and that is not what C# looks at it as.  Thanks for the help, that was very frustrating.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how you'd have trouble starting with that sort of assumption. My debug hint would be that if you'd looked at what `GetType` returned you'd have hopefully been pointed in the right direction of realising that the values weren't types themselves. I had to go look up how to get the attribute off the values though. ;-)