# Get property of custom attribute for enum

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

My project has this BookDetails attribute:

```
public enum Books
{
    [BookDetails("Jack London", 1906)]
    WhiteFange,

    [BookDetails("Herman Melville", 1851)]
    MobyDick,

    [BookDetails("Lynne Reid Banks", 1980)]
    IndianInTheCupboard

}
```

and code for attribute here:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class BookDetails : Attribute
{
    public string Author { get; }
    public int YearPublished { get; }

    public BookDetails(string author, int yearPublished)
    {
        Author = author;
        YearPublished = yearPublished;
    }
}
```

How do I get the author for a given Book?

Tried this messy code but it didn't work:

```
 var author = Books.IndianInTheCupboard.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false).GetType().GetProperty("Author");  // returns null
```

Thanks, there's got to be a better way than what I was trying above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the attribute is attached to an `enum` field, you should apply `GetCustomAttribute` to `FieldInfo`:

```
var res = typeof(Books)
    .GetField(nameof(Books.IndianInTheCupboard))
    .GetCustomAttribute<BookDetails>(false)
    .Author;
```

Since attribute type is known statically, applying generic version of the `GetCustomAttribute<T>` method yields better type safety for getting the `Author` attribute.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/E6Q6UR)

Comment: The code in your "Demo" link works but the code in the snippet does not. I had an error with "nameof" method. The assingment to the variable res works in the demo code with this line: 
var res = typeof(Books).GetField("IndianInTheCupboard").GetCustomAttribute<BookDetails>(false).Author;

Comment: @C_Sutt [The modified version of the demo](https://ideone.com/DwUoEF) works fine.

Comment: Woops, I copied the wrong line. I meant the one in your post, not the demo. var res = typeof(Books)
    .GetField(nameof(Books.IndianInTheCupboard))
    .GetCustomAttribute<BookDetails>(false)
    .Author;

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work because you are trying to find attribute of the type Books, but not attribute of the enumeration element.
It works.

```
var fieldInfo = typeof(Books).GetField(Books.IndianInTheCupboard.ToString());
var attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BookDetails), false).FirstOrDefault() as BookDetails;
var author = attribute.Author;
```

If you need to get values of this attribute often you can write extension for it.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static BookDetails GetDescription(this Books value)
    {
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BookDetails), false).FirstOrDefault() as BookDetails;

        return attribute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Love the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Already by [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value) Bryan Rowe. Replication of his solution accord your example:

```
    var type = typeof(Books);
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(Books.IndianInTheCupboard.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BookDetails), false);
    var description = ((BookDetails)attributes[0]).Author;
```