# Setting value in-line

Tags: c#, .net

With all the awesome stuff we can do in C#, I was wondering if we could do something like the below:

```
  string totalWording =
  {
    if (isA)
      return "Value A";

    if (isB)
      return "Value B";

    if (isC)
      return "Value C";

    return "Default";
  };
```

So this would be very similar to the ?: except you can have more than 2 possible outcomes

```
string totalWording = isA ? "Value A" : "Default";
```

I could happily create a method that returns the value, but I'm a big fan of being able to see the simple stuff straight away

```
private string GetTotalWording()
{
  if (isA)
    return "Value A";

  if (isB)
    return "Value B";

  if (isC)
    return "Value C";

  return "Default";
}
```

I'd like to hear if anybody has something nice I can use, or if I'm just living on a prayer.

Edit:

There is the func option too, which is what I suppose got me onto the topic, as it looks you should be able to straight-up use a function when declaring a value.. but that might just be me

```
    Func<string> getTotalWording = () =>
    {
      if (isA)
        return "Value A";

      if (isB)
        return "Value B";

      if (isC)
        return "Value C";

      return "Default";
    };
```

Comment: A statement is either true or false, in your method you are checking 3 different bools, I could convert your GetTotalWording to a ternary(?:) expression quite easily but I don't think its what you're looking for. Should the result be `Value A` if all 3 are true for instance?

Comment: What if `isA` and `isC` are both true, or is it only possible for one to be true at any given time?

Comment: Or does he want just to take the first thing that's true, regardless of whether the later ones are true?

Comment: The logic I've been supplied is hierarchical, so whatever comes first is used.

Comment: In which case the nested ternary shown by Amit will do this, but going for "clever" one liners over simple, readable code is a common mistake.

Comment: You can have nested functions nowadays, perhaps that would help? Do you just want to keep the logic inside one method? You could nest the function in that method.

Comment: I was thinking that - I'll edit it my post so we can all see the option. But yes, this logic is only being used once.

Comment: @Oyyou Updated an enum sample as well. Do check.

Answer (score 3):

Use repetitions of ternary operator.

```
string totalWording = isA ? "Value A" : (isB ? "Value B" : (isC ? "Value C" :  "Default"))
```

There is another way, if you only have manage-able number of if's and they remain same always. Create an enum with string values.

[Below answer is based on another on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799401/7974050)

You can create an enum for these statements with description.

```
public enum Values
    {
        [Description("Value A")] A,
        [Description("Value B")] B,
        [Description("Value C")] C,
        [Description("Value D")] D
    }
```

Then, you can create a function to get enum description

```
private static string GetEnumDescription(string text)
{
    var valueAttribs = typeof(Values).GetMember(text)[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return ((DescriptionAttribute)valueAttribs[0]).Description;
}
```

and you can then use these as

```
var variable = "A";

    string description = 
      (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Values), variable)) ? 
          GetEnumDescription(variable) : "Default";

    Console.WriteLine(description);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Oh damn, son. I was thinking of something like that, but it didn't quite come out. Interesting. I'll see if anything else comes up before marking as answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, if I were to take this route - I'd be splitting with lines. The logic I'm currently using isn't too overwhelming.

Comment: @Oyyou Seriously though, don't do this. It's so unreadable compared to the first version. (And splitting it with lines doesn't really give you any advantage over the original easy-to-read-and-understand version.)

Comment: I think I have used this in the past (when just learning the ?: operator), and it did look nasty.

For the time being, I'll be sticking with the get method.

Unless of course, somebody comes up with something magical.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest the method and lay it out more succinctly, so it looks more like this:

```
void someMethod(bool isA, bool isB, bool isC)
{
    string totalWording() {
        if (isA) return "Value A";
        if (isB) return "Value B";
        if (isC) return "Value C";
        /*Else*/ return "Default"; }

    // Other code...

    string s = totalWording();

    // Etc
}
```

I personally find that more readable.

If you can't use C# 7 you can do a similar thing with a Lambda in earlier versions, as you've already noted in your question. I'll put a copy here for completeness:

```
void someMethod(bool isA, bool isB, bool isC)
{
    Func<string> totalWording = () => {
        if (isA) return "Value A";
        if (isB) return "Value B";
        if (isC) return "Value C";
        /*Else*/ return "Default"; };

    // Other code...

    string s = totalWording();

    // Etc
}
```

The reason I strongly prefer this to the version using the ternary operator is that when reading the ternary version I have to mentally translate it into the above code when trying to understand it.

If I have to do that, then I'd rather it was written down for me so I didn't need to expend the effort. Perhaps that's just me, and I'm lazy. ;)

Comment: Is that valid syntax, or is that only available in a later version of C#? I'm currently only able to use VS2015.

Comment: @Oyyou I'm afraid that's C# 7 or later (so you'd need VS2017)

Comment: Ah, that's fair. I do remember reading about a better way than using the ugly, and easily forgettable Func<string>.

Comment: @Oyyou I added the `Func<string>` thing for completeness anyway. ;)