# How to add space between two words in c# enum list

Tags: c#

I want to space in enum in c#.**Like : FabricRollManagement to Fabric Roll Management**
I need enum list not a single value.where i pass a enmu list and return a list that contain multiple value

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Do you need it for display purposes? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value) ?

Comment: Do you want the _`string` manipulation_ that turns the string `"FabricRollManagement"` into the string `"Fabric Roll Management"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, C# doesn't allow whitespace in variable, class or any declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can not do it to code, but you can display it.

```
String save;
foreach (x in yourenum.toString().toCharArray()) {
    if Char.isUpper(x) save += " " + x;
    else save += x;
 }
```