# loop through Enum and retrieve EnumString

Tags: c#

In an attempt to build a Dictionary object that is seeded with all possible system statuses as the keys and 0 for each value, I have the following code that loops through the Enum that contains system status info:

```
            Dictionary<string, int> statusAccumulator = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            // initialize statusAccumulator with all possible system statuses
            foreach (var status in Enum.GetNames(typeof(SystemTaskRequestStatus)))
            {
                statusAccumulator[status] = 0;
            }
```

and here is the Enum for system status:

```
public enum SystemStatus
{
    [EnumString("PN")]
    Pending,
    [EnumString("RT")]
    Retry,
    [EnumString("IP")]
    InProgress,
    [EnumString("C")]
    Complete,
    [EnumString("F")]
    Failed,
    [EnumString("T")]
    Test
}
```

With this code, the keys in the Dictionary are: Pending, Retry, InProgress, Complete, Failed, Test.  However, I want the EnumStrings as the keys - PN, RT, IP, C, F, T.  How can the code be modified to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Comment: Why would you want to? Is `statusAccumulator[SystenStatus.Pending]` too long? The point of an enum is to reduce ambiguity, not create it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do Enum.GetValues(typeof(SystemStatus)), apply foreach, cast each item back to enum then use whatever method that retrieves the string from the property?

```cs
foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SystemStatus))
{
    string key = (SystemStatus)status.MethodThatRetrievesTheThingyFromProperty();
    statusAccumulator[key] = 0;
}
```

However, is there a reason why you don't want to use `SystemStatus` as `TKey` and use the enum instance itself to get/set the value?

```cs
Dictionary<SystemStatus, int> statusAccumulator = new Dictionary<SystemStatus, int>();

// initialize statusAccumulator with all possible system statuses
foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SystemStatus))
{
    statusAccumulator[(SystemStatus)status] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace you enum code with this,
    `public enum SystemStatus
        {
            [StringValue("PN")]
            PN = 1,
            [StringValue("RT")]
            RT = 2,
            [StringValue("IP")]
            IP = 3,
            [StringValue("C")]
            C = 4,
            [StringValue("F")]
            F = 5
            [StringValue("T")]
            T = 6
        }`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not permitted to modify the enum code.

Comment: You actually do not need the [StringValue] attributes from that point, as you could simply call ToString() on enum instances.