# Custom Attributes for fields

Tags: c#

I did a custom attribute for fields that receives a string.
Then I'm using the custom attribute in an enum.
I need to get the result of "MyMethod" from FieldAttribute, but It doesn't return the string,

Here's what I have:

Enum and attribute:

```
public enum CustomEnum
{
    [Field("first field")]
    Field1,
    [Field("second field")]
    Field2,
    [Field("third field")]
    Field3
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class FieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public FieldAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string MyMethod()
    {
        return this.name + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintInfo(typeof(CustomEnum));
    }

    public static void PrintInfo(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Information for {t}");
        Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t);

        foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is FieldAttribute)
            {
                FieldAttribute a = (FieldAttribute)attr;
                Console.WriteLine($"   {a.MyMethod()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some help please!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

```
public static void PrintInfo(Type t)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Information for {t}");

    var pairs =
        from name in t.GetEnumNames()
        let member = t.GetMember(name).Single()
        let attr = (FieldAttribute)member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), false)
                      .SingleOrDefault()
        let text = attr.MyMethod()
        select (name, text);

    foreach (var (name, text) in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine($"{name} -> {text}");
}
```

Explanation: you are using `GetCustomAttributes` on the type, but you need actually the enum constants which are indeed [fields on the enum type](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACBmAAjgDsBXMAgYVNgHswBRMsAWACgBvdgnggMTRwMAEwCMSbrwFDhAJglte/QSLzsAvuyA==). So you need to get the `MemberInfo` for the enum constant and ask for its attribute.

---

For a really old compiler you can use a simple

```
public static void PrintInfo(Type t)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Information for {t}");

    foreach (string name in t.GetEnumNames())
    {
        MemberInfo member = t.GetMember(name).Single();
        FieldAttribute attr =
            (FieldAttribute)member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), false)
                      .SingleOrDefault();
        string text = attr.MyMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(name + " -> " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's "name" and "text"  in
select (name, text);

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS8130 Cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable 'name'. I got this error

Comment: @Westbrook: `name` is defined on `from name in names`, `text` in `let text = attr.MyMethod()`

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS8130 Cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable 'name'.

Comment: @Westbrook: Which VIsual Studio version / language version do you use?

Comment: a quick hack might be: `foreach (var pair in pairs) Console.WriteLine(pair.name + " -> " + pair.text);`, but for a down-level compiler, it might need more love - perhaps switching to `select new { name, text };`