# Get attribute from Enum knowing only the PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, attributes

#### What I have:

I have a class where many of the properties use a specific type of attribute. This class also contains a property which is a nullable enum, and each value of the enum may also be decorated with the same attribute. For example:

```
// My basic class
public class Upgrade
{
    [Abbreviation("name")]
    public int string Name { get; set; }

    [Abbreviation("opt")]
    public bool Optional { get; set; } = true;

    [Abbreviation("type")]
    public UpgradeType? TypeOfUpgrade { get; set; } = null;
}

// My basic enum
public enum UpgradeType
{
    [Abbreviation("fl")]
    Full, 

    [Abbreviation("prt")]
    Partial
}

// My basic attribute
public class AbbreviationAttribute: Attribute 
{
    public string Value{ get; private set; }

    public AbbreviationAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

#### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to get the name of each property and it's value. However, if the property is decorated with the `AbbreviationAttribute`, the value from the attribute should be used instead. Likewise, if the property is **any** type of enum, the value should be taken from the enum's `AbbreviationAttribute`, if it has one.

So for an object such as this:

```
Upgrade upgrade = new Upgrade 
{
    Name = "First Upgrade",
    Optional = false,
    TypeOfUpgrade = UpgradeType.Full
};
```

I'd like to output the string:

> name=First Upgrade;opt=false;type=fl

How can I achieve this?

#### What I've tried:

I've can get the attribute from the property, however I'm not sure how to access it from the enum property. So in the above example, I can get the `AbbreviationAttribute` from the `TypeOfUpgrade` property, but since it's an enum, I need to get the `AbbreviationAttribute` from it's value.

```
string values = string.Empty;
// foreach property
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // get the attribute from the property, if it exists
    AbbreviationAttribute attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<AbbreviationAttribute>();

    if (attr != null)
    {
        //append the value from the attribute, instead of the property name
        values += $"{attr.Value}=";

        // if property is an enum (nullable or otherwise)
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsEnum || pi.PropertyType.IsNullableEnum())
        {
            // get the type of enum
            Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType);
            if (type == null)
            {
                type = pi.PropertyType;
            }

            // --------------------------
            // Now I have the type of enum, and the value from the PropertyInfo,
            // how can I access the AbbreviationAttribute that's on the enum's value? 

        }
    }
}

// helper method
public static bool IsNullableEnum(this Type t)
{
    Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    return (u != null) && u.IsEnum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum value is a static field of the enum type.

So once you have an enum value, you get the `Type` for the enum type, get the field info for the enum value, and get the attribute from the member info.

```
public static TAttributeType GetEnumValueAttribute<TAttributeType>(Enum val) 
    where TAttributeType : Attribute
{
    if (val == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return 
        val.GetType().
        GetMember(val.ToString())?.
        FirstOrDefault()?.
        GetCustomAttribute<TAttributeType>();
}
```

And in your loop:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // get the attribute from the property, if it exists
    AbbreviationAttribute attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<AbbreviationAttribute>();

    if (attr != null)
    {
        //append the value from the attribute, instead of the property name
        values += $"{attr.Value}=";

        // if property is an enum (nullable or otherwise)
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsEnum || pi.PropertyType.IsNullableEnum())
        {
            values += $"{GetEnumValueAttribute<AbbreviationAttribute>((Enum)pi.GetValue(obj))?.Value};";
        }
        else
        {
            values += $"{pi.GetValue(obj)};";
        }
    }
}
```

You're really asking a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799401/424129). I copied his code, but modernized it a bit.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I'd actually stumbled upon the question you've linked, but was struggling to apply it to my scenario, and wasnt sure if it was even possible.