# Convert Enum From String To Int In DB Then Back To String - Entity Framework Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Enum similar to this:

```
    public enum Type
    {
        TypeA,
        TypeB,
        TypeC
    }
```

I have this using Fluent API and Entity Framework 3.0:

```
    builder.Entity<Element>()
        .Property(p => p.Type)
        .HasConversion<int>();
```

This converts the string coming in and saves it in the DB as an int. However, when I do a query to pull it out of the DB it is staying an int.

I have read the docs but I cannot seem to understand:

How do I take the string of the Enum - convert it to an int for the DB - then receive a string when I query the DB?

I thought maybe it was using EnumToNumberConverter but it takes two arguments and I have no idea what the second argument should be. As seen in these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Can anyone please give me a concrete example of how I convert an Enum's string to integer when storing in the DB and then when querying it get handed the Enum's string again?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need using convertors, EF Core stores Enums as an `Integer`. So, using `.HasConversion<int>();` is not needed anymore. EF Core reads this value as an Integer and casts it to the `Type` when you send a query. Therefore, you have a `Type` that you can use `Type.Sample.ToString()` to using string value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're right, I don't need that. It was my front end TypeScript Enum that was casting it back to a number. So it was coming out my API a string again and then in the front end a TS Enum was casting it back to a number. Now to figure out how not to cast it back to a number. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have a (preferably microsoft) source saying "EF Core stores Enums as Integer" ? I need it to convince other developpers to use enums instead of magic numbers in their entities

Comment: @Inspi  I think for persuading to not using magic numbers you don't need an EF-related reference, Either integer constants or Enums can be used for this purpose depending the case

Answer (score 0):

This will return the enum string:

```cs
enum E : int
{
    Element1 = 42
}
//...
int i = 42;
string s = ((E)i).ToString();// returns "Element1"
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this wasn't what I was asking. I appreciate it though!