# How to create object list from enum

Tags: c#, enums

below is the Enum from which i need to populate object list

```
public enum Scope
    {
        [Description("Organization")]
        Organization = 100,
        [Description("Organization@Unit")]
        Organization_Unit = 200,
        [Description("Organization@Unit@User")]
        Organization_Unit_User = 300
    }
```

I have to create object list from this Enum

Object skeleton will be like below

```
public class ScopeKVP {
  public string key {get;set;}
  public int value {get;set;}
}
```

At the end I need below list of object from enum in which `description` of each enum should be save in `key` property of object and `value` of enum should be saved in `value` property of object like below

```
var scopeKvp = new List<ScopeKVP> {
    new ScopeKVP {key= 100,value="Organization"},
    new ScopeKVP {key= 200,value="Organization@Unit"},
    new ScopeKVP {key= 300,value="Organization@Unit@User"}
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value) quesiton shows how to get the attributes from the enum values. Constructing the list should then be easy. (Note that `key = 100` is wrong when `key` is of type `string`).

Comment: Here's an article on this on how to get attributes and their values from instances: https://www.codementor.io/@cerkit/giving-an-enum-a-string-value-using-the-description-attribute-6b4fwdle0

Comment: And I'd recommend to use a `Dictionary<Scope,string>` instead of the list.

Comment: TBH, This is looks like a misuse of the enum language feature

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

1. Use reflection to get the information about the enum, its fields
2. Loop the fields
3. Take their value with `GetValue` method
4. Take the attribute `Description`'s description, which is what you passed to
   its constructor
5. Create the object of type `ScopeKVP` and add it to
   the result list

Code:

```
    Type enumType = typeof(Scope);
    FieldInfo[] fields = enumType.GetFields();

    List<ScopeKVP> scopeKvp = new List<ScopeKVP>();
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.IsLiteral)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute descAttr = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

            ScopeKVP item = new ScopeKVP()
            {
                key = descAttr.Description,
                value = (int)field.GetValue(null)
            };

            scopeKvp.Add(item);
        }
    }

    // scopeKvp is what you need
```

P.S. like the comments above state, you have some mismatch for `key` which is string and you expect integer. I guess it is a typo.