# Accessing raw value of an enum in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

In WebForm days you would have just used ToString to get the text description from the enum all the other examples are about the Display Attribute but its not working for me.In .net core all i want to get is the text of enum

```
public  class FileAttachments {
 public enum FileAttachmentType {
   [Display(Name = "Vessel")]
   Vessel = 21,
   [Display(Name = "Person Of Intrest")]
   Poi =22,
   [Display(Name = "Case")]
   Case =23,
   [Display(Name = "Passport Documents")]
   Passport =25,
   [Display(Name = "Certificates")]
   Certificates =26,
   [Display(Name = "Licenses")]
   Licences =27,
   [Display(Name = "Witness Statements")]
   WitnessStatements =28,
   [Display(Name = "Photo Evidence")]
   PhotoEvidence =29        
 }
  public int FileUploadTypeValue  { get; set; }    
}
```

I am Storing the value in FileUploadTypeValue  but when I try to access the help method I have to go for example in the model level FileUploadTypeValue will have the value 22 for POI which should print out on screen for me Person Of Interest which is the Display Name of Poi=22

```
@foreach (var file in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="fiv-cla fiv-size-lg fiv-icon-@file.Extension"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
@HelperMethods.GetDisplayName(@file.FileUploadType)

        @file.FileUploadType
    </td>
        <td>@file.CreatedDate</td>
    <td>@file.File</td>
    <td>@file.UploadedByUser.FirstName @file.UploadedByUser.LastName</td>
                 
    <td><a target="_blank" href="/Uploads/@file.File">View File</a></td>

</tr>
}
```

In MY Helper Class I have the following

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
{
  return enumValue.GetType()?
                .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())?
                .First()?
                .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                .Name;
}
```

Its this line its not liking what should i be passing to get the string so for 22 I should get Person Of Interest instead of poi

```
@HelperMethods.GetDisplayName(@file.FileUploadType)
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799401/2791540)

Comment: @JohnWu no as i want to do it in razor not markup i did state that.

Comment: I can't help but notice that your enumeration is called `FileAttachmentType` but you are passing a `FileUploadType`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @JohnWu FileUploadType is the value field ie it will hold 22 for POI.

Comment: So what problem are you having? Is there a compiler error or is it not working as you expect at runtime?

Comment: I cant get it to show the text instead of the value so that is the error

Comment: Have you tried debugging and hitting a breakpoint in your method? Maybe the method is returning null and the "poi" you see is because you have `@file.FileUploadType` directly in the razor after the method call

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is `FileUploadType` an `int`?

Comment: @JohnWu yes FileUploadType  is an int but I have a enum declared for it

Comment: @JohnWu i edded the question to make it more clear what FileUploadType is and changed the name to FileUploadTypeValue

Comment: Have you tried casting it? `@HelperMethods.GetDisplayName((FileAttachmentType)@file.FileUploadType)`

Comment: @JohnWu  I will try that this afternoon thank u  in work at present that what i was not sure of how to cast it so it was reconized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `EnumHelper` I used before.

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
{
    public static IList<T> GetValues(Enum value)
    {
        var enumValues = new List<T>();

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            enumValues.Add((T)Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), fi.Name, false));
        }
        return enumValues;
    }

    public static T Parse(string value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }

    public static IList<string> GetNames(Enum value)
    {
        return value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
    }

    public static IList<string> GetDisplayValues(Enum value)
    {
        return GetNames(value).Select(obj => GetDisplayValue(Parse(obj))).ToList();
    }

    private static string lookupResource(Type resourceManagerProvider, string resourceKey)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo staticProperty in resourceManagerProvider.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (staticProperty.PropertyType == typeof(System.Resources.ResourceManager))
            {
                System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = (System.Resources.ResourceManager)staticProperty.GetValue(null, null);
                return resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
            }
        }

        return resourceKey; // Fallback with the key name
    }

    public static string GetDisplayValue(T value)
    {
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        var descriptionAttributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute[];

        if (descriptionAttributes[0].ResourceType != null)
            return lookupResource(descriptionAttributes[0].ResourceType, descriptionAttributes[0].Name);

        if (descriptionAttributes == null) return string.Empty;
        return (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0) ? descriptionAttributes[0].Name : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Get `IList<string>` of `Display Name` from Enum

```
EnumHelper<FileAttachmentType>.GetDisplayValues(FileAttachmentType.Vessel)
```

Get `string` of `Display Name` from Enum

```
EnumHelper<FileAttachmentType>.GetDisplayValue(FileAttachmentType.Vessel)
```

Comment: EnumHelper I posted worked for me. Due to confusing about the relationship between FileUploadType an FileUploadTypeValue, I didn't provide test for your models. You could try it by yourself and if you need further help, please detail your models.

Comment: Sorry what should FileAttachmentType the main model is called FileAttachmentVM should that be there.

Comment: Do use this   @EnumHelper<FileAttachmentType>.GetDisplayValues(FileAttachmentType.Vessel)
 its not reconizing EnumHelper even though i added it using stament and the class to project