# What is the difference between using the C# Description attribute and XML documentation comments (triple-slash comments)?

Tags: c#, attributes, comments, xml-documentation, xml-comments

Is there a difference between using the C# Description attribute and XML documentation comments (triple-slash comments)? When should I use either one?

Thanks.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my class.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is my field.
    /// </summary>
    public int myField = 1;
}
```

vs.

```
[Description("This is my class.")]
public class MyClass
{
    [Description("This is my field.")]
    public int myField = 1;
}
```

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666875/get-xml-documentation-comments) might help.

Comment: @madreflection: Thank you. The question title was a bit different, hence I could not find it. It answers my question. Could you please post that in an Answer, that I may accept it?

Comment: In that case, it would be a duplicate, as it would be a link-only answer within Stack Overfow. It's because the title was different (and it was framed differently) that I didn't flag it as a duplicate from the start. If you have the ability to accept it as a duplicate, please do so. Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Marked as a duplicate. Thank you for the help.